# Phpstan function doc callable and parameters

Tags: php, generics, phpstan

Is there any way to pass parameters in doc from callable to function baz $params?
I need give parameters in array associated by its names.

```
interface Bar {

    /**
     * @template TResult of mixed
     * @template TParam of mixed
     *
     * @param callable(TParam...):TResult $callable
     * @param array<array-key,TParam>     $params
     *
     * @return TResult
     */
    public function baz( callable $callable, array $params ): mixed;

}
```

```
/** @var Bar $bar */
$bar = '...';

$bar->baz(
    fn( int $a, float $b, ?bool $c = null ) => $a, // phpstan error here 
    [ 'a' => 1, 'b' => .1, 'c' => null ]
);
```

```
phpstan error: phpstan: Parameter #1 $callable of method Bar::baz() expects callable(float|int|null ...): int, Closure(int, float, bool|null=): int given.
```